# How to advise your barber

Tags: halacha, hair, how-to, payot-sideburns

Men: What is a succinct, clear, [Halachically complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payot) line to tell a barber what not to do when cutting your hair?

Comment: I'm trying out and demonstrating the bounty feature here. The idea is that I'd really like an answer to this question, but it's been up for a while now without a sufficient answer. Whoever gives the best answer within a week gets a nice little reputation bonus. If you have questions in a similar situation, consider starting a bounty.

Comment: As you can see, doing this makes your question prominent in a few ways: It gets bumped to the top of the recent-activity list, it gets a striking bounty label, and it makes it to the Featured tab.

Comment: Tell the barber not to "clean up" in front of the ear.

Comment: "My Wahl is my barber". --Bet Chesed in Hashkafah.com thread ["Can I still go to a yeshivish barber though I'm no longer in yeshiva?"](http://www.hashkafah.com/index.php?/topic/67635-can-i-still-go-to-a-yeshivish-barber-though-im-no-longer-in-yeshiva/).

I too now cut my own hair with electric [hair clippers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_clipper). It's convenient and inexpensive. It went fine even the first time I tried it.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B097XGMLHF/

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks! Ordered.

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't read it. I just saw an ad for it today. Do let us know how it turns out

Comment: @DoubleAA I've read and liked other works by [R' Chaim Jachter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Jachter), so it strikes me as a safe bet that it'll be well-researched and well-written.

Answer (score 8):

There is a [poster](http://kosherhaircut.com/) available online.

If you will keep it in the barber shop they promise to send it to you a free copy.

---

**EDIT**
The website seems down. There is a backup poster on [the Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20120117200700im_/http://kosherhaircut.com:80/fullsize.html)

Comment: The website is back up again

Answer (score 6):

I've found the best policy asking to "leave the sideburns intact" and then taking care of the minor job myself at home. I realize this is a non-answer, but it has proven more successful at achieving the desired result of not appearing to have cut my hair in a forbidden way than other forms of instruction.

Comment: Why is this a non-answer? ....the question asked for what you might tell your barber, and you answered that.

Comment: @Shokhet It doesn't say what not to do.

Comment: Why isn't this a "succint, clear, Halachically complete" line to tell your barber? ....he does nothing, and hence does not mess up.

Answer (score 6):

Find a friend and ask: וואו איז א גוטער שערער
When you arrive ask: איך וויל זיך אפשערן
If you're still in doubt mention: שערט ניט פון די פאות
(See "Say it in Yiddish" by Uriel Weinreich and Beatrice Weinreich page 132)

If this doesn't work then its a little harder to give a one sentence explanation but I think it can be done.

I would suggest saying something like this:

> "Please do not *shave*/remove/cut too short/**touch** the hair
>   from behind/in front of my ear to the temple/back of my hair line and
>   below." While doing so touch the various points to help illustrate
>   your intent. Then watch like a hawk.

The Shulchan Aruch (Y.D. 181:9) gives the dimensions  of the *peyos*. As I understand it it says that the area extends from the hair opposite the forehead down past the ear to the joint where the lower jaw begins. The entire width is included in the *peyos* which I presume to mean until [at least] in front of the ear.

Nitei Gavriel - Chinuch Yeladim, Halachot & Minhagim has a section, I believe chapter 6, which discusses the minhagim (especially Chassidish ones) associated with peyos. In the back ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46552&st=&pgnum=198) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46552&st=&pgnum=199)) it has some nice diagrams illustrating the different areas (which I need to study further). As I recall there are two areas really in in question.

One is how far up on the forehead: One appears to be the furthest point forward of the hair line, the other is the point where the natural hair line dips furthest back (which is higher on the head).

The second is the back edge of the *peyos*: one of which was placed in front of the ear the other half way past the ear (or more likely behind where the ear attaches at the head).

Additionally some arch the line between these two points up.

(It really helps to look at the pictures)

I think this is a sufficient explanation to keep one out of too much trouble but one needs to speak to a Rav who is familiar with the basic halachah and your own customs.

Answer (score 5):

It seems no one has discussed how long the hair actually needs to be.

The Mishna in Niddah 6:12 states

> שתי שערות האמורות בפרה ובנגעים והאמורות בכל מקום כדי לכוף ראשן לעיקרן דברי רבי ישמעאל ר"א אומר כדי לקרוץ בציפורן ר"ע אומר כדי שיהו ניטלות בזוג
> The [length of the] two hairs regarding the Red Heifer, the Tzara'at affliction, and in all places is enough to bend their top to their root, according to R Yishmael. R Eliezer says they must be long enough to catch with one's fingernail. R Akiva says they must be long enough to cut with a scissors.

The gemara there comments ([Niddah 52b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=52b&format=pdf))

> אמר רב חסדא אמר מר עוקבא: הלכה כדברי כולן להחמיר.‏
> Rav Chisda said in the name of Mar Ukeva: The Halacha is like all of them in the most stringent way [i.e for every instance pick the opinion that is most stringent].

So, we have to decide which length is longest and how long it is. According to [here](http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak65/11halak.htm) the longest length is the first opinion (bending head to root). I have never done any personal research, but according to [this site](http://www.koshershaver.org/why.htm) and confirmed by a number of people I have spoken to about this, the minimum length necasary to satisfy all opinions is a #2 clipper guard. So as long as you are getting your hair cut longer than that, you needn't worry about what area of the head they are trimming.

(All translations are mine)

Comment: Assuming the system you're familiar with is the one I am, that means a quarter of an inch. [Apparently, though, YMMV.](http://menshair.about.com/od/forhaircareprofessionals/tp/Clipper_Blade_and_Clipper_Guard_Sizes.htm) It would be best to get and relay _p'sakim_ in absolute lengths, which people could then translate to guard sizes on their own. +1, though, nice answer.

Comment: @msh210 I always thought guard lengths were standard. I've always just been told a #2 and that's also what the quoted site says. I don't know an exact length to tell you.

Comment: @msh210 It seems like most of those guards have 1/4 inch as a number 2. So that sounds like a good guess for an absolute length.