# Chafetz Chaim's opinion on how long peos need to be

Tags: halacha

The [Biur Halacha 251:on seif 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.251.2.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) discusses the issur of cutting ones payos off. From what I understand from the Biur Halacha is that even the smallest amount of hair left may be good enough.Is that what he means?

...
וכמבואר כ"ז בש"ע יורה דעה סימן קפ"א ע"ש גם אחד המקיף ואחד הניקף הוא בכלל לאו זה וכמבואר שם ובעו"ה מצוי שמעבירין את הפאות עד סמוך לבשרן ממש ואין משיירין כלל ויש בזה חשש דאורייתא והיה להם לשייר עכ"פ קצת מן הקצת וביותר מזה יש מהבחורים שבעת שהספר מספר ראשו הוא מגלח לו השער שאצל אזנו והוא מחמת שמוטעין שחושבין שפאת הראש נקרא רק מה שאנו קורין פאה ולא כן הוא כאשר כתבנו והוא לאו גמור דאורייתא לד"ה וגם זה הלאו הוא אפילו על הניקף וכנ"ל ...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26312 (and see the end of [Matt's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50785) where he mentions this).

Comment: It looks like what he means...

Comment: He may be saying that leaving even a little bit would at least satisfy some opinions (but perhaps shouldn't be done lechatchila), while what 'they' are doing is completely forbidden according to everyone.

Comment: @doubleAA that's how I really understood it as well,but from the the way it's written it seems that leaving a very close shave is fine,I dk

Answer (score -1):

from Niddah 52b

מתני׳ שתי שערות האמורות בפרה ובנגעים והאמורות בכל מקום כדי לכוף ראשן לעיקרן דברי רבי ישמעאל ר"א אומר כדי לקרוץ בציפורן ר' עקיבא אומר כדי שיהו ניטלות בזוג

Comment: This answer could be a great deal more valuable if you'd [edit] in your basis for asserting that this is the Chofetz Chaim's opinion, whether your basis is a verbal or oral source or whether it's reasoning based on what you've seen in the Chofetz Chaim's or others' words.

Comment: @IsaacMoses you are right

Comment: interesting response. Besides connecting this to the chafetz chaim's opinion about the length of peyos what are you basing the connection of this mishna to the subject of payos from?

Answer (score -1):

This is  just  anecdotal but Rav Ruderman used to say over that as a Bocher learning in Slabodka he once went to visit the Chofetz Chaim.The  CC criticized him  for two things (1)he was wearing a red  tie (2)his peyos were too short.

Even more anecdotal and of even less bearing on the question.  There is a picture  of Rav Mendel Zaks with bochurim in Radin. Most, but not all, of them had very short peyos.  Not knowing who they were you  wouldn't even be sure they were frum (The  CC was either no longer alive  or  no longer involved in the Yeshiva when the picture was taken)

Comment: Short and thin is two diff things