# Darchei Teshuva on someone that cuts his peyos very close with scissors b'shogeg not being punished for it

Tags: payot-sideburns

Aryeh Leibowitz writes, "See Darchei Teshuva 181:2 who rules that one who unwittingly followed the ruling of the Rambam need not repent for his sin, as the Shulchan Aruch rules that the strict halacha is in accordance with this view."  Can someone tell me exactly where Darchei Teshuva says this?  I tried to find it but I couldn't.  It should be somewhere around here https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14570&st=&pgnum=472

Comment: Is there a way to post where you saw this qoute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's on the next page in comment #4.

> עיין בשו"ת זרע יצחק חיו"ד סימן י"ב שנשאל באחד שגלח הפאות במספרים סמוך לבשר כעין תער וסבר שמותר לעשות כן ועכשיו נודע לו שהיא אסור ורוצה לקבל תשובה מה יהא תשובתו והשיב דלדעתו אין צריך לקבל תשובה כיון שהמחבר לא הכריע כדעת האוסרין וכתב רק בלשון יש לחוש לדבריהם ועל כל פנים כם דעת הרמב"ם המקיל בזה יש לו מקור בש"ס על כן על כל פנים לענין התשובה על לשעבר בשוגג יש לסמוך על דעת הרמב"ם להקל עי"ש באורך
> See responsum Zera Yitzchak, Yoreh Deah #12, who was asked about one who shaved his *peot* with scissors close to the skin like a razor and thought it was permitted to do that and now he knows it is forbidden and wants to accept penance what should his penance be. And he answered that in his opinion there is no need to accept penance since the Shulchan Arukh did not decide in favor of the prohibitive opinions but just wrote that it is appropriate to worry about them and at the very least the opinion of the Rambam, who is the lenient position here, has a basis in the Talmud, therefore at least regarding penance for a accidental past action we should rely on the opinion of the Rambam to be lenient. See there at length.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26314/759