# Why are Payos HaRosh and Peyos HaZakein treated differently?

Tags: halacha, payot-sideburns, beard

The source for halachos regarding Peyos HaRosh (sidelocks) and Peyos HaZakein (beard) comes from [Vayikra 19:27](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.19.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> לֹ֣א תַקִּ֔פוּ פְּאַ֖ת רֹאשְׁכֶ֑ם וְלֹ֣א תַשְׁחִ֔ית אֵ֖ת פְּאַ֥ת זְקָנֶֽךָ׃
> You shall not round off the side-growth on your head, or destroy the side-growth of your beard.

My question is: If many halachic authorities permit the use of electric shavers ([see here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shaving#cite_ref-13)) would they also allow the same thing to be used for the sidelocks? Or would such a length in *that* area be too short? It seems like certainly that would not be allowed because it would leave the Peyos HaRosh area too short.

Why are the two areas treated differently when learned from the same verse?

Now, I understand that there is a difference in the wording; one says do not round, one says do not destroy. Is that the difference?

Comment: re: electric shavers on peyos https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26314/759

Comment: I believe you answered your own question.

Comment: As you can see here, https://www.sefaria.org.il/Leviticus.19.27?lang=bi&with=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Negative%20Mitzvot&lang2=en Rambam counts them as two different Mitxvos, and it is completely irrelevant that those appear in the same verse. As two different commandments they are subjects to different properties and Halochos.