# How long do you really need to keep your sideburns?

Tags: halacha, shaving, payot-sideburns

I've seen multiple sources that seem to indicate that one MUST keep his sideburns to either

1. The bottom of the ear
2. The bottom of the ear cartilage
3. To the jaw bone, around the middle of the ear.

When looking this up online, I came across [this psak halacha from R' Abadi](http://kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=6125&highlight=payos), in which he indicates that one who shaves with an electric shaver need not worry about any of this and only needs to leave a few rows of hair remaining in the payos area.

Is this a valid option? Is the practice to keep the sideburns long, as most yeshivishe people do, just a chumra?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for bringing your question here. Keep in mind that we [try to avoid practical halachic questions](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734). You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: FTR, I voted this as a psak question. *Is this a valid option?* Yes, according to R' Abadi. No according to the first opinions.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26312/5323

Comment: I am not talking about the length of the hairs themselves, but rather the lowest point of the payos area and the possibility of it being permissible to remove the payos (or at least part of them) with an electric shaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sources from Shulchan Aruch - [Yoreh De'ah - 181](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_27.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

Regarding the shaver in the Payos area:

> **ג:** אֵינוֹ חַיָּב אֶלָּא בְּתַעַר. וְיֵשׁ אוֹסְרִים בְּמִסְפָּרַיִם (ב) כְּעֵין תַּעַר, וְיֵשׁ לָחוּשׁ לְדִבְרֵיהֶם. ‏
>
> באר היטב  (ב) כעין. שגוזז במספרים סמוך לבשר כעין תער. ש''ך: ‏

As [Matt](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50760/501) pointed out, it's a matter of dispute. The Shulchan Aruch brings 2 opinions:

1. It's only forbidden to use a razor.
2. Even using scissors is forbidden. (When cutting close to the skin, not trimming, as per the Be'er Heitev.)

The Shulchan Aruch votes for the second opinion; he wouldn't approve of shaving in the Payot area.

As opposed to the beard area where only a razor is forbidden.

> **י:** אֵינוֹ חַיָּב עַל הַשְׁחָתַת פְּאַת הַזָּקָן אֶלָּא בְּתַעַר, אֲבָל בְּמִסְפָּרַיִם מֻתָּר, אֲפִלּוּ כְּעֵין תַּעַר. ‏

As to "leave a few rows of hair remaining in the payos area" (and the area defined as Payot):

The Shulchan Aruch says that the area includes all the hair in line with the forehead and the ear, until the bottom of the ear where the jawbone gets wide.

"In this entire area **one should not touch**". This makes it sound like he wants one to leave all the hair intact in that area.

> **ט:** שִׁעוּר הַפֵּאָה מִכְּנֶגֶד שֵׂעָר שֶׁעַל פַּדַחְתּוֹ וְעַד לְמַטָּה מִן הָאֹזֶן, מָקוֹם שֶׁהַלֶּחִי הַתַּחְתּוֹן יוֹצֵא וּמִתְפָּרֵד שָׁם, וְכָל רֹחַב מָקוֹם זֶה לֹא תִּגַּע בּוֹ יָד.  ‏

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [170:1](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0169_L2) also seems to understand it that way.

> סימן קע - אסור גלוח פאות הראש והזקן
>
> **סעיף א':** פְּאוֹת הָרֹאשׁ הֵן שְׁתַּיִם בְּסוֹף הָרֹאשׁ, וְהוּא מְקוֹם חִבּוּרוֹ לַלֶּחִי מִיָמִין וּמִשְׂמֹאל אֵצֶל הָאֹזֶן. וַאֲפִלּוּ **לְגַלְּחָן בְּמִסְפָּרַיִם כְּעֵין תַּעַר, דְּהַיְנוּ סָמוּךְ לַבָּשָׂר, שֶׁאֵינוֹ מְשַׁיֵר כְּלוּם מִן הַשְּׂעָרוֹת סָמוּךְ לַבָּשָׂר, יֵש אוֹסְרִין**. וְלָכֵן אִם צָרִיךְ לְגַלְּחָן לִרְפוּאָה, יִזָּהֵר שֶלֹּא לְגַלְּחֵן סָמוּךְ לַבָּשָׂר מַמָּשׁ. **וְשִׁעוּר הַפֵּאָה מִכְּנֶגֶד שֵׂעָר שֶׁעַל פַּדַּחְתּוֹ וְעַד לְמַטָּה מִן הָאֹזֶן, מְקוֹם שֶׁהַלְּחִי הַתַּחְתּוֹנָה יוֹצֵאת וּמִתְפָּרֶדֶת** שָׁם. ‏

The קיצור ש''ע ילקוט יוסף in [181:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_49.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2) also frowns on shaving that area.

> ויש אומרים שאיסור מקיף הוא גם במספריים כעין תער, **ויש לחוש לדבריהם**.

It would seem that R' Abadi is relying on the opinion that the Shulchan Aruch - and summaries thereof - mention, but they all say one should choose the other opinion.

You ask:

> Is this a valid option?

Seems to be, as everybody mentions it.

> Is the practice to keep the sideburns long, as most yeshivishe people do, just a chumra?

Not in the usual sense, as the Shulchan Aruch tells one to behave that way. Usually we'd define a Chumra as following a minor opinion, not one the Shulchan Aruch prefers.

Comment: Thanks! According to the second opinion of the SA, what is the point that one must keep the sideburns to? Where does the idea of the payos going to "the bottom of the ear" come from?

Comment: @user8613 - I'm not sure. See Rashi on Kidushin 35b and Makos 20b and Tosafos on Nazir 41b. That's the closest I can get. Seems the Shulchan Aruch learns that the Payot "צדעיו" continue until where the beard starts. See the Gemara that says (Makos 20b) ת''ר פאת ראשו סוף ראשו ואיזהו סוף ראשו זה המשוה צדעיו .

Answer (score 4):

If I recall, R. Moshe Feinstein is cited in Megged Giv'os Olam as holding that any hair that does not grow in until the onset of puberty may be shaved.

I heard this from Rabbi Heineman as well.

Answer (score 2):

See Rabbi Leibowitz's article section E [here](http://www.yutorah.org/mobile/?shiurID=735346)

1. The Shulchan Aruch writes they need to go down to the bottom of the ear.
2. Rabbis Zilber and Arik maintain this does not include the earlobe as part of the ear.
3. Rabbis Frimmer and Belsky maintain any clear differentiation between hair types, I.e. color or texture, is enough to recognize where peyos of the head ends and peyos of the beard begin.
   (As noted in a different answer, Rabbi Feinstein is quoted by Rabbi Shurkin as having said this as well)

Answer (score -1):

Rav Yehudah Pfeuffer, son of R. Aharon Pfeuffer zt"l of South Africa and author of a sefer on electric shavers, writes the following in his kuntres on hilchos peyos:

המנהג אצל המון העם וגם בני הישיבות לספר זקנם עד לחי העליון. וכל מי שרואה תמונות הישיבות מלפני המלחמה רואה כן בבירור. וכבר צווח ע"ז הח"ח בכל המקומות הנזכרים בקו' זה.
ומצאתי בשו"ת באר משה ח"א סימן ס"ב אות ט' שהאריך לתמוה על המנהג (והאריך שם בדברי הארץ צבי הנ"ל), ומסיק דמחמת טרחת הגלויות לא החמירו הרבה על העם בזה. 
ויש לזה סמך, דמאחר שמשתמשים במספריים כעין תער שמעיקר הדין מותר כמו שכתב המחבר בסעיף ג' רק כתב דרך חשש להחמיר וכמו שביאר בשו"ת מהר"י שטייף ס' ע"ח וע"כ כיון שדעת ריב"ן הוא יחיד בראשונים למעיין שם, הורגלו להקל במספריים כעין תער ודו"ק . 
וכיום רואים שכל אחד עושה שיעור אורך שונה מחבירו, ולא זכיתי להבין דעתם בזה דמאחר שמקילים כנגד הריב"ן מדוע לא יגלחו עד הלחי העליון.  וכך שמעתי ממו"ר הגר"י פורטנוי שליט"א והגר"מ שורקין שליט"א שהגר"מ פיינשטיין הורה להם כן דעד מקום הלחי העליון מקום שיש לתינוק שיער מותר לגלח. (ולשון זה הוא בב"ח מספר קרבן אהרון). וכן נהגנו בבית אאמו"ר ז"ל בילדותי.

Comment: Not useful without a summary - even a word-for-word translation would be almost useless.

Comment: Please summarize the quoted paragraph.