# Where to find a Jewish Barber?

Tags: product-recommendation, hair, payot-sideburns, beard, haircuts

I recently moved from New York out west.  I travel between Tucson, Phoenix, Las Vegas and Los Angeles.  I am looking for a Jewish Barber who is experienced properly cutting hair giving consideration to beards and payos. If anyone knows of a barber in any of these areas, I'd be appreciative. Finding an experienced Jewish barber is not all that easy.

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97

Comment: The guide referenced in msh210's comment above is all you need to take to your ( uninformed-on-laws) barber.