# Halachicly Correct Haircut Length for Jewish Male Clients and Barbers

Tags: halacha, hair, payot-sideburns

I have questions about halachicly correct haircut length for Jewish male clients and barbers:

- Are peot (פאות) required for a halachicly correct haircut?
  What is the minimum length requirement for the peot area in millimeters?
- Is there a minimum length requirement for haircuts, and can a haircut include fades that reach scalp-visible lengths such as that of a #1 guard (3mm) and lower, such as with common low and mid fades and tapers?
- Is it permissible to completely trim off all the hair to a minimal length of the instrument used during a halachicly correct haircut such as commonly done for simple buzz cuts or bald clients?

Thank you in advance for your help in answering these questions.

Comment: Hi @7c5f3e - and welcome to MiYodeya, you are asking a lot of good questions but this is perhaps too much for one question alone. Perhaps think about allowing a bit more focus in the question by splitting these up as individual questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26312/759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to advise your barber](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-advise-your-barber)